# Using Haskell ADT members' constructors as types

Tags: haskell, adt

I have an algebraic data type like this:

```
type Keyword = Text

data DBField = (:=) Keyword DBVal
  deriving (Show, Read, Eq)

data DBVal = VNull
           | VInt Int64
           | VDouble Double
           | VBool Bool
           | VString Text
           | VUTCTime UTCTime
           | VArray [DBVal]
           | VObjId ObjectId
           | VUUID UUID
           | VRecord [DBField]
  deriving (Eq, Show, Read)
```

as my `VRecord` has a lot of operations on it, I need a way to define functions like:

```
get :: VRecord -> Keyword -> Maybe DBVal
get r k = ...
```

but since `VRecord` is a data constructor, I have to define my functions like this:

```
get :: DBVal -> Keyword -> Maybe DBVal
get r@(VRecord _) k = ...
get _ _ = ...
```

which both reduces readability (mainly in documentation) and also forces me to deal with other cases of `DBVal` type. So what's the best way to deal with this situation?

Comment: If you were able to define the function like that, how would you use it?

Comment: @FyodorSoikin The use cases wont change, I Just want my signatures to be clear about what they require, i.e `VRecord` instead of a generic `DBVal`. Also dont wanna have to deal with other cases.

Comment: If the use cases won't change, it means they would still be passing a parameter of type `DBVal`, right? If so, what should happen if a particular `DBVal` turns out to be, say, `VNull`?

Comment: @FyodorSoikin that's the whole point, i dont want to have to deal with cases like that, so i want my function to have a type of `VRecord`, so a `VNull` *can't* be passed in.

Comment: But in that case the use sites also have to change, right? They can't keep passing in `DBNull`, can they? So they have to change somehow. So my initial question stands: what would a use site look like?

Comment: @FyodorSoikin call sites are supposed to pass `VRecord`, i want a way to catch it in compile time if they pass anything else.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be done with Liquid Haskell:

```
module DB where

import Data.Text
import Data.Int
import Data.Time

type Keyword = Text

data DBField = (:=) Keyword DBVal
  deriving (Show, Read, Eq)

data DBVal = VNull
           | VInt Int64
           | VDouble Double
           | VBool Bool
           | VString Text
           | VUTCTime UTCTime
           | VArray [DBVal]
           | VRecord [DBField]
  deriving (Eq, Show, Read)

{-@ measure isVRecord @-}
isVRecord (VRecord _) = True
isVRecord _ = False

{-@ type VRecord = {v:DBVal | isVRecord v} @-}

{-@ get :: VRecord -> Keyword -> Maybe DBVal @-}
get :: DBVal -> Keyword -> Maybe DBVal
get (VRecord xs) k = undefined

test :: Maybe DBVal
test = get VNull (pack "test") -- error
```

Try it here: http://goto.ucsd.edu:8090/index.html#?demo=permalink%2F1629647897_38731.hs

Comment: Here the use site can still pass in `VNull`, but the OP states that shouldn't be possible

Comment: Would this cause a compile time error or a runtime error? if its compile time its good enough for me.

Comment: ok it catches them at compile time. thanks!

Comment: @FyodorSoikin no the example is rejected by the Liquid Haskell type checker, see the demo.

Comment: @Noughtmare for the life of me i cant get LH to work with my project (yesodweb/simple template with stack), im getting a stack overflow when compiling. Any ideas?

Comment: @FarzadBekran I would use the GHC plugin as described here: https://ucsd-progsys.github.io/liquidhaskell-blog/2020/08/20/lh-as-a-ghc-plugin.lhs/. You also might want to add `-fplugin-opt=LiquidHaskell:--no-termination` if you run into many unexpected Liquid Type Mismatches.

Comment: @Noughtmare it didn't help. still getting the same stack overflow error :( guess ill have to wait for LH to get a bit more mature.

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps we could lift an auxiliary sum type using `DataKinds`, and turn `DBVal` into a GADT indexed by the auxiliary type. A simplified example:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}
data DBType = TNull
            | TInt
            | TDouble
            | TBool
            | TString
            | TArray 
            | TRecord 
  deriving (Eq, Show, Read)

data DBVal (t :: DBType) where
  VNull :: DBVal TNull
  VInt :: Int -> DBVal TInt
  VDouble :: Double -> DBVal TDouble
  VBool :: Bool -> DBVal TBool
  VString :: String -> DBVal TString
  VArray :: [SomeDBVal] -> DBVal TArray
  VRecord :: [DBField] -> DBVal TRecord

data SomeDBVal where
    SomeDBVal :: DBVal t -> SomeDBVal
```

Now we can write a function like

```
get :: DBVal TRecord -> Keyword -> Maybe SomeDBVal
get r@(VRecord _) k = ...
```

without having to consider the other branches. The exhaustivity checker knows that the only possible branch is `VRecord` and doesn't complain.

Because `DBVal` is now a GADT, we can't auto-derive `Eq`, `Show`, and `Read`. We must write the instances ourselves.

Also, we need the auxiliary `SomeDBVal` wrapper for when we don't want to bother with the `DBType` type index.

`VArray` and `VRecord` contain `SomeDBVal`s, so we won't be able to use the more precise version of `get` on the sub-components.

---

I'm not sure I understand the motivation for this though. If you get your `DBVal`s from an outside source, it's unlikely that they will arrive "tagged" with enough information to identify them as `VRecord`s. So it seems that you'll need to pattern-match in any case.

Comment: Interesting solution! ill have to try this later. regarding the "tagged" `DBVal`s, im actually saving the schemas of the records in the db itself and validate them, so i will be using the schemas to marshal the incoming data to the required types.

Comment: It's not that you are completely unable to  use the precise `get` with a `SomeDBVal`; you just have to pattern match on the `DBVal` constructor first in order to learn what the type parameter is. It makes sense at that point, as you're *not* guaranteed to have a `VRecord`, so you need to say what to do if it isn't (the other cases of the pattern match). This setup means you don't have to handle alternative possibilities on *every* `get` (inside the definition of `get`), only on the ones where you haven't proved that `VRecord` is the only possibility.

Comment: There shouldn't be any difficulty deriving `Show`, I don't believe, using `StandaloneDeriving`. I'm not terribly optimistic about `Eq` (though it would be possible in theory), and `Read` would have to be instantiated separately for each index (GHC *could* derive those, but I doubt it knows how).

Answer (score 4):

The other answers look quite complicated to me. I think it should be simple: don't take a `DBVal`, take the field of the constructor you know you have. So:

```
get :: [DBField] -> Keyword -> DBVal
get fields = ...
```

Define other operations on records similarly. The compiler will then enforce that callers *know* their `DBVal` is a `VRecord` -- because they won't have access to the `[DBField]` inside unless they (or their ancestor) has used a pattern-match to check that property dynamically.

If you really must, you can define a lifting operation to do this pattern match once and for all, but I probably wouldn't; in almost all cases I'd massage the callers instead, since they're going to invariably have their own ideas about what to do with values that aren't records. But, if you do want such a lift, it might look like

```
onRecord :: a -> ([DBField] -> a) -> (DBVal -> a)
onRecord def f val = case val of
    VRecord fields -> f vields
    _ -> def
```

Then you have, for example,

```
onRecord (error "not a record") get :: DBVal -> Keyword -> DBVal
```

Comment: I get what you're saying, but the problem is since `[DBField]` can contain nested `VRecord`s, i would have to pattern match again and again on the field values now to traverse the tree, which is less than ideal in my opinion.

Comment: @FarzadBekran I will be very impressed if you somehow find a solution that operates on a nested data type without having nested pattern matching.

Comment: let me clarify a bit: instead of 'pattern match, extract fields, pass it to next fn and receive a `VRecord` or `[DBField]`', I would rather 'be sure what I have is a `VRecord`, pass it down and receive a `VRecord`'.Granted this might not be possible or easy to do, but since I'm new to Haskell I wanna make sure before I give up on it. Also maybe if I could define a Monad instance on `VRecord` somehow, it could be a better.